# JOptionpane + JDialog (non-modal) get the return value

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog, non-modal

I have a non-modal dialog with two input text fields shown with the JOptionPane with OK and CANCEL buttons. I show the dialog as below.

```
        JTextField field_1 = new JTextField("Field 1");
        JTextField field_2 = new JTextField("Field 2");

        Object[] inputField = new Object[] { "Input 1", field_1,
                "Input_2", field_2 };

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(inputField,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "Input Dialog");
        dialog.setModal(false);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
```

How can i get the return value from the dialog? Means i need to get whether Ok or CANCEL button is pressed. How can achieve this?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [getValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#getValue%28%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add a `ComponentListener` to the `dialog` and listen for its visibility to change,

```
dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        if ((int) optionPane.getValue()
                == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            // do YES stuff...
        } else if ((int) optionPane.getValue()
                == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            // do CANCEL stuff...
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unexpected Option");
        }
    }
});
```

Note: you should probably use the `ComponentAdapter` instead; I'm showing the whole interface for illustration.

Comment: I tried this and none of the Overriden methods are called when interacting with the JOptionPane.

Comment: @MarkCramer I did notice my answer had a compile time error, which I've fixed. But other than that, I took the code from the question and this answer and it seems to work as expected. Could you perhaps create a question to provide an example of where it's not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

[Using getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#getValue%28%29) will tell you how the dialog was closed. Since it's non-modal, you'll need to get that information once the dialog is closed, probably using a `Thread` that will wait that your dialog is closed to return the information. You don't give any details on what needs that information, so using another `Thread` might not be the best solution for you.